# why I can't send mail to gmail after configuring send mail to use gmail as SMTP mail relay

Tags: linux, email, networking, sendmail, centos6

I am using centos 6.4, and installed sendmail with the instruction given in this blog

http://www.mavinerc.com/home/2012/04/29/howto-configure-linux-sendmail-to-use-gmail-as-smtp-mail-relay/

I believe (not sure) that I have configured sendmail successfully with `gmail id` and `password`, and now I can send mail to only local domain say for example my domain name is `example.com`,  so I can send mail to any users of `example.com`, but If i try to send to some other domain say `user@gmail.com` or `user@yahoo.com` I am getting error message `Deferred : Connection timed out with alt4.smtp.in.goo`

I tried `ping` as well as `telent` both are failed for both port `25` and `587`, I can't ping even to google.com

```
     $ ping google.com
     PING google.com (74.125.236.174) 56(84) bytes of data.
     ^C
     --- google.com ping statistics ---
     37 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 36287ms

     $ telnet smtp.gmail.com 25
     Trying 74.125.25.108...
     Trying 74.125.25.109...
     Trying 2607:f8b0:400e:c03::6c...
     telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Network is unreachable

     $ telnet smtp.gmail.com 587
     Trying 74.125.25.108...
     Trying 74.125.25.109...
     Trying 2607:f8b0:400e:c03::6c...
     telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Network is unreachable
```

what could be the issue ? whether its related to iptables on my host ? Should I contact Network Administrator ?

Comment: Your problem at the moment is not with sendmail. There is definitely a problem with the underlying network connection or configuration. This question is more likely to be [on-topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) at [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com).

Answer (score 0):

Totally agree - there is a network issue.
1.Try to check your IP address and default GW.
2.ping you default GW and after that try : 
traceroute google.com